# Android project has lost touch with Resources. Everything seems broken

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml, android-resources

I don't know what's happened and it's scaring me.

The project seems to be detached from my resources somehow. If I change the id of a resource (`R.id.myId` to `R.id.myId2`), the project continues to run and operate fine as if `R.id.myId` still exists. If I create a new string (`R.string.newStr`), then my java code doesn't know about it. It will complain that the resource doesn't exist.

What was I doing when this started? I was adding array resources for FAQs. I created a new file, `my_arrays.xml`, as seen below. I put a few dummy entries and ran it to make sure it worked. It did. At this point, my xml looked like the following (I've recreated it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="faq_questions_array">
        <item>What\'s the news?</item>
        <item>Is this good?</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="faq_answers_array">
        <item>All news is news?</item>
        <item>The best ever</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

So I put the real FAQs in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="faq_questions_array">
        <item>What can this app do?</item>
        <item>How do I add a course?</item>
        <item>Can I edit or remove a course?</item>
        <item>Can I edit/remove/view details of a grade?</item>
        <item>How do I set the current semester?</item>
        <item>How do I account for GPA from previous semesters? Do I have to manually recreate all grades from every course ever? </item>
        <item>Why is a lot of my text red?</item>
        <item>I found a bug. What should I do?</item>
        <item>Do you have any sagely advice for my academic career?</item>
        <item>What is something I should try?</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="faq_answers_array">
        <item>It can track your grades in your classes so that you stay organized and aware in face of slipping scholarships</item>
        <item>There\'s a button. Main screen.</item>
        <item>Well, you probably could if you pressed the menu button while on the course\'s screen.</item>
        <item>Yup. When looking at your grade category (e.g., "Quizzes") tap the grade you want to mess with</item>
        <item>The semester defaults based on the time of year it is and/or isn\'t. You can change it in the settings menu from the home screen.</item>
        <item>Hilariously, yes! Seriously, no. Set your old credit and GPA in the Settings screen.</item>
        <item>Because you're not studying enough.</item>
        <item>It might be carrying diseases. Best kill it. Or email it to me at NSouthProductions@yahoo.com and I\'ll kill it for you.</item>
        <item>Stay on top of your schoolwork. Know when things are due and how much time you'll need to prepare. Go with your gut on a tricky question, but analyze it and follow what's logical. But then remember your gut feeling and let your mind challenge it. Let your gut and mind duke it out and go with either.</item>
        <item>Corn on pizza. They do it in Europe and it is delicious. Add broccoli for real yums. </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I ran my app and got... this. It was still using the old strings, even though they no longer existed in my xml.

[image]

Now I find that my resources seem to be completely detached. I have searched my project for these old strings and cannot find them. I've restarted Eclipse, my computer, the genymotion emulator (and reinstalled on it). The project continues to run as if the resources are exactly what they were right before I completed my FAQ, regardless of the contents of the XML files.

Help.

Comment: Check all of ur values folder.

Answer (score 1):

be sure your xml file haven't any error then do this :

Project --> clean --> clean all project

and :

project --> Build automatically

good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the errors. My _R.txt_ file is gone and rebuilding doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: i am sure your xml file has error because when you have error in xml file, R.java not creating check everything in res folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this before. You need to clean up the project and do a rebuild.

In the menu bar of Eclipse, find "Project", and then click "Clean...", "Clean all projects", "OK".

Comment: Hmm now I have `R cannot be resolved to a variable` all over my java code.

Comment: That's normal. Now click on your project name on the left panel, and then press F5 to refresh. Then do a rebuild (it will probably automatically rebuild if you just try to launch your app).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the errors. My _R.txt_ file is gone and rebuilding doesn't seem to do anything. I can't launch my project because I have 400 errors now.

Comment: Again, that's really normal. You can always close your Eclipse and reopen. After you restart Eclipse, give it a few minutes to build and associate, and all your 400 errors will be gone at once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new workspace.
2. Import your project (without R.java).
3. Go to project and make sure auto build is unchecked.
4. Go to project and build it.
5. R.java should show up.
6. You can enable auto build now.